# Text concerning units in $O_K$ of an algebraic number field $K$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I have not done much of algebraic number theory, and want to buy a book which explores the techniques/methods and proves the results and theorems concerning structures of ring of integers of an algebraic number field K and finding units in ring of integers of an algebraic number field K.

For this aim which algebraic number theory text (or any other text) is best.

Thanks!

Comment: D. Marcus' "Number Fields" is an old but very good book in my opinion.

Comment: Marcus' book is quite good, but it organizes much of the topics in the exercises. I suggest you another good book, Stewart and Tall's "Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem". You can find it [at this link](http://kashanu.ac.ir/Files/Content/ANT.pdf).